How to move submit row to the top of the Django admin panel
I have pretty large list of objects so I would like to move the "save" button in the Django admin panel to the top of the list of objects, rather than the bottom.
This would be similar to the result shown in the attached image.


Add save_on_top = True in your ModelAdmin class.
